# Does Eclipse have a way to alphabetically sort lines within a selection of text?

Tags: eclipse, sorting, emacs, lines

Similar to emacs' M-x sort-lines

Comment: Are there any alternatives that do not involve mimicking Emacs? People that have never used Emacs before would also like to sort lines, but are not interested in an Emacs emulator.

Comment: [Johan Zandin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15462446) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66766761) saying "AnyEdit (mentioned in other answers) have now moved here: [https://github.com/iloveeclipse/plugins/wiki/AnyEdit-Tools](https://github.com/iloveeclipse/plugins/wiki/AnyEdit-Tools)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this plugin for Eclipse:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs

If the above one doesn't do the job, try one of these ones:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/emacs

Comment: sadness, I'm stuck with Eclipse 3.5 for now.  No Marketplace Client (and thus emacs plugin) for me.

Comment: No. You can use it for sure. See the additional details: it works in Eclipse Versions: Ganymede or later. Your Eclipse version is Galileo - see this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases, that is, you have a newer version of Eclipse than that of Ganymede, so you can use it.

Comment: um.... that link only takes me to the Eclipse download page.  Says all downloads already have MPC installed.  But I'm running 3.5 and I don't have it installed.  Am I suppose to manually install this Marketplace Client module myself, then use it to install the Emacs plugin?

Comment: You can access the market place from the Help menu within Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry to keep pushing this, but... I'm not seeing it in my help menu.  I have "Check for Updates" and "Install New Software", but no "Eclipse Marketplace".  I'm running Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Build id: 20100218-1602

Comment: So, OK. I have Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers too (my version is 3.6 Helios and it does have the Market Place menu option). But you can install it anyways. Click the Install New Software menu option. Then copy and paste this URL into the Work with field: http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site. Click the Add button and give whatever name to it. It should now display the Emacs package. Select it and click next. Voila.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Sadness that I can only up-vote you once.

Comment: hehehe... you're welcome. I'm here to help. I'm glad with your up vote.

Comment: um, sorry, last question -- how do I activate the emacs plugin?  Do I need to set my keybindings to "emacs" mode?  (didn't seem to work)

Answer (score 38):

Yes, it does! There is a very simple plugin called [SortIt](http://www.stateofflow.com/projects/2/sortit) that does exactly what you want. It adds a section in the Edit menu, through which you can do the following:

- Case Sensitive
- Case Insensitive
- Reverse Text
- Numeric Sort
- Length Sort

The plugin is source-code agnostic, and it treats whatever you sort as plain text. I find it especially useful when sorting `.properties` files and setters/getters. For example, using the Case Sensitive sorting I sorted the following code:

```
msgHeader.setTotalGrossMass(content.getTotalGrossMass());
msgHeader.setReferenceNumber(content.getReferenceNumber());
msgHeader.setTransportModeAtBorder(content.getTransportModeAtBorder());
msgHeader.setCountryOfDestinationCode(content.getCountryOfDestinationCode());
msgHeader.setCountryOfDispatchExportCode(content.getCountryOfDispatch());
msgHeader.setDateOfAmendment(content.getDeclarationDate());                     // TODO: correct?
msgHeader.setIdentityOfMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder(content.getIdentityMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder());
msgHeader.setManualEntryNumber(content.getManualEntryNumber());
msgHeader.setTotalNumberOfPackages(content.getTotalNumberOfPackages());
msgHeader.setAgreedLocationOfGoodsCode(content.getAgreedLocationCode());
msgHeader.setAgreedLocationOfGoodsLNG(content.getAgreedLoclOfGoodsLNG());
msgHeader.setManualEntryYear(content.getManualEntryYear());
msgHeader.setAgreedLocationOfGoods(content.getAgreedLocationCode());
msgHeader.setMethodOfPayment(content.getMethodOfPayment());
msgHeader.setNationalityOfMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder(content.getNationalityMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder());
msgHeader.setAmendmentPlace(content.getDeclarationPlace());                     // TODO: correct?
msgHeader.setAmendmentPlaceLNG(content.getDeclarationPlaceLNG());               // TODO: correct?
msgHeader.setTotalNumberOfItems(content.getTotalNumberOfItems());
msgHeader.setAcceptanceDate(content.getAcceptanceDate());
```

... to this:

```
msgHeader.setAcceptanceDate(content.getAcceptanceDate());
msgHeader.setAgreedLocationOfGoods(content.getAgreedLocationCode());
msgHeader.setAgreedLocationOfGoodsCode(content.getAgreedLocationCode());
msgHeader.setAgreedLocationOfGoodsLNG(content.getAgreedLoclOfGoodsLNG());
msgHeader.setAmendmentPlace(content.getDeclarationPlace());                     // TODO: correct?
msgHeader.setAmendmentPlaceLNG(content.getDeclarationPlaceLNG());               // TODO: correct?
msgHeader.setCountryOfDestinationCode(content.getCountryOfDestinationCode());
msgHeader.setCountryOfDispatchExportCode(content.getCountryOfDispatch());
msgHeader.setDateOfAmendment(content.getDeclarationDate());                     // TODO: correct?
msgHeader.setIdentityOfMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder(content.getIdentityMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder());
msgHeader.setManualEntryNumber(content.getManualEntryNumber());
msgHeader.setManualEntryYear(content.getManualEntryYear());
msgHeader.setMethodOfPayment(content.getMethodOfPayment());
msgHeader.setNationalityOfMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder(content.getNationalityMeansOfTransportCrossingBorder());
msgHeader.setReferenceNumber(content.getReferenceNumber());
msgHeader.setTotalGrossMass(content.getTotalGrossMass());
msgHeader.setTotalNumberOfItems(content.getTotalNumberOfItems());
msgHeader.setTotalNumberOfPackages(content.getTotalNumberOfPackages());
msgHeader.setTransportModeAtBorder(content.getTransportModeAtBorder());
```

Comment: Hrm, I get the error: `Operation is not enabled` when I try to use it.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't have a problem in Helios. Why don't you contact the maintainer, in case this is an incompatibility?

Comment: +1. btw After adding the update site for SortIt in Eclipse, there will be TWO options to choose from: "State of Flow" and "Uncategorized". To avoid installation errors chose **"State of Flow"**.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm using it to sort my PHP imports. Couldn't be happier!

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Eclipse - Mars. Just does nothing after install and restart from the menus.

Comment: 2019-March - SortIt is no longer available from the Eclipse marketplace, nor the links above. It seems to only exist at https://github.com/channingwalton/eclipse-sortit

Comment: SortIt is dead. Use AnyEdit instead! It works great. See the other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632206/does-eclipse-have-a-way-to-alphabetically-sort-lines-within-a-selection-of-text/14899278#14899278.

Answer (score 18):

Horribly ugly website, but [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) does sorting:

- Case sensitive
- Case insensitive
- Numerical
- Backward
- Forward

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)
This plugin should be implemented in one of the next Eclipse-releases! :D

Comment: AnyEdit works great! More info here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools. To use after installing: **select a bunch of lines → right click → Sort → Case-Sensitive A-z**. Done!

Answer (score 6):

With luna you can do this by "Source" -> "Organize Imports"

This works for every type of line, not just imports.

Comment: Provide an example of how this works for non-import lines please

Comment: Select the lines you want to be sorted and activate the "Organize Imports" action.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore on later versions of Eclipse. On Eclipse 2021-12 I had a non-Java file and the "Organize Imports" action wasn't even available. But even when I cut-pasted the lines I wanted to sort into a Java file and ran "Organise Imports" on it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can confirm that it still works with eclipse 2022-06.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse Kepler SR2 I can see an option under `Source > Sort Members..`
It works.

I also have [**AnyEdit**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Works for me with Kepler.

If it doesn't work, goto Help->Key Assist... and look for "Sort Lines"

EDIT: seems to work only in the C/C++ Editor and therefore probably comes with the CDT

Comment: `CTRL` is `STRG` on German keyboards. But `CTRL` + `ALT` + `S` does not work for me on Kepler SR2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under Linux, simply use "cat file | sort". Under Windows, as a programmer, you should probably have cygwin installed anyways.

Comment: OP wanted a "selection of text"

Comment: The question was about Eclipse, right? Also only part of text was in question also named 'selection'.